# Upload CSV file into Microsoft Azure storage account using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to upload a `.csv` file into Microsoft Azure storage account using python. I have found [C-sharp](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/08/03/converting-between-azure-tables-and-csv/) code to write a data to blob storage. But, I don't know `C#` language. I need to upload `.csv` file using python.

**Is there any example of python to upload contents of CSV file to Azure storage?**

Comment: Are you able to provide the csv with some sample data with the headers you want?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage) reference link. My following code perfectly work for **uploading** and **downloading** `.csv` file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='<myaccount>', account_key='mykey')
block_blob_service.create_container('mycontainer')

#Upload the CSV file to Azure cloud
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    'mycontainer',
    'myblockblob.csv',
    'test.csv',
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/CSV')
            )

# Check the list of blob
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs('mycontainer')
for blob in generator:
    print(blob.name)

# Download the CSV file From Azure storage
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('mycontainer', 'myblockblob.csv', 'out-test.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to upload the data of `csv` file into Azure Table Storage. According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) of python`csv` package & the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-table-storage) for Azure Storage Python SDK, I made the sample code & csv data as below.

For example, the data of my testing csv file as below.

```
Name,Species,Score
Kermit,Frog,10
Ms. Piggy,Pig,50
Fozzy,Bear,23
```

And the sample code.

```
import csv
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')
table_service.create_table('csvtable')

csvfile = open('test.csv', 'r')
fieldnames = ('Name','Species','Score')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
rows = [row for row in reader]
for row in rows:
  index = rows.index(row)
  row['PartitionKey'] = '1'
  row['RowKey'] = '%08d' % index
  table_service.insert_entity('csvtable', row)
```

Hope it helps.