# AzureException: HTTPSConnectionPool : Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to upload a csv/pdf files to azure blob storage using python locally.

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978833/upload-csv-file-into-microsoft-azure-storage-account-using-python), but this throws an error,

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='account_name', account_key='key1')
block_blob_service.create_container('cn1')
block_blob_service.set_container_acl('cn1', public_access=PublicAccess.Container)

#Upload the CSV file to Azure cloud
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    'mycontainer',
    'C:/uploads/blob.csv',
    'C:/uploads/blob.pdf',
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/CSV')
            )
```

After uploading i want to use the uploaded file to process.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       block_blob_service.create_container('cn1')
>
> File
>   "c:\users\rb287jd\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py",
>   line 600, in create_container
>       self._perform_request(request)
>
> File
>   "c:\users\rb287jd\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py",
>   line 280, in _perform_request
>       raise ex
>
> File
>   "c:\users\rb287jd\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py",
>   line 252, in _perform_request
>       raise AzureException(ex.args[0])
>
> AzureException:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='account_name.blob.core.windows.net',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cn1?restype=container
>   (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to
>   account_name.blob.core.windows.net timed out. (connect timeout=20)'))

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following changes?

a) Add the missing import:

```
from azure.storage.blob import PublicAccess
```

b) Create the block blob service as follows if you're using the Azure Storage Emulator:

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(is_emulated=True)
```

c) Change the container name to **cn1** instead of **mycontainer**, which is the one being created early in the code:

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    'cn1',
    'C:/temp/blob.csv',
    'C:/temp/blob.pdf',
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/CSV'))
```

In addition, please make sure:

a) Azure Storage Emulator is running during your local tests. Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator.

b) You have the right storage account name and key by opening using Storage Explorer (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

I was able to get the script working after the changes mentioned above on both Azure Storage Emulator and Azure itself using the appropriate method signature to create the block blob service.

Comment: Thank you . But the above error comes from the line "block_blob_service.create_container('cn1')" I am unable to connect to azure blob. I am wondering if this is correct because I am connecting to Azure blob from the local python.

Comment: I've updated the answer with instructions to run your script against the Azure Storage emulator. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error:
AzureException: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='account_name.blob.core.windows.net', port=443):

This means any of following:

1. Your URL is HTTP and not HTTPS
2. Your account name is not fully qualified: It should be
   http(s)://server ip or name/accountname
3. You are using emulator and not specifying in the connection something as follows:
   blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME,account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY, is_emulated=True, protocol='http')